# Can't train faster rcnn

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, deep-learning, faster-rcnn

I want build my own Faster Rcnn model, I download an example from https://github.com/dBeker/Faster-RCNN-TensorFlow-Python3

I get an error when running the code, and I don't know why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/l/Desktop/Faster-RCNN/train.py", line 216, in <module>
    train.train()
  File "C:/Users/l/Desktop/Faster-RCNN/train.py", line 148, in train
    blobs = self.data_layer.forward()
  File "C:\Users\l\Desktop\Faster-RCNN\lib\layer_utils\roi_data_layer.py", line 75, in forward
    blobs = self._get_next_minibatch()
  File "C:\Users\l\Desktop\Faster-RCNN\lib\layer_utils\roi_data_layer.py", line 71, in _get_next_minibatch
    return get_minibatch(minibatch_db, self._num_classes)
  File "C:\Users\l\Desktop\Faster-RCNN\lib\utils\minibatch.py", line 30, in get_minibatch
    im_blob, im_scales = _get_image_blob(roidb, random_scale_inds)
  File "C`enter code here`:\Users\l\Desktop\Faster-RCNN\lib\utils\minibatch.py", line 67, in _get_image_blob
    im, im_scale = prep_im_for_blob(im, cfg.FLAGS2["pixel_means"], target_size, cfg.FLAGS.max_size)
  File "C:\Users\l\Desktop\Faster-RCNN\lib\utils\blob.py", line 35, in prep_im_for_blob
    im = im.astype(np.float32, copy=False)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Comment: I suggest to look at `blob.py` line `35`, apparently the `im` object is `None`, check why

Comment: you can ask the question [here](https://github.com/dBeker/Faster-RCNN-TensorFlow-Python3/issues)

Comment: Probably some thing is wrong with your input images, because they are not being read in the model. It can be the **name, path, type, ...** of one image or more.

Comment: I think I know how to deal with it.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For building your own `Faster RCNN Models`, you can follow the instructions mentioned in the [Official Tensorflow Github Repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1af55e018eebce03fb61bba9959a04672536107d/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md).

The advantage of following these instructions is that if you face any problem, you can file an issue in [this Repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues) and you will be assisted by Google Engineers.

Specifying the steps mentioned in the [Github Repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1af55e018eebce03fb61bba9959a04672536107d/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md) for the benefit of the community (just in case that link breaks).

**Defining a new Faster R-CNN or SSD Feature Extractor:**

In most cases, you probably will not implement a `DetectionModel` from scratch --- instead you might create a new feature extractor to be used by one of the SSD or Faster R-CNN meta-architectures. (We think of meta-architectures as classes that define entire families of models using the `DetectionModel` abstraction).

Note: For the following discussion to make sense, we recommend first becoming familiar with the [Faster R-CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497) paper.

Let’s now imagine that you have invented a brand new network architecture (say, “InceptionV100”) for classification and want to see how InceptionV100 would behave as a feature extractor for detection (say, with Faster R-CNN). A similar procedure would hold for SSD models, but we’ll discuss Faster R-CNN.

To use InceptionV100, we will have to define a new `FasterRCNNFeatureExtractor` and pass it to our FasterRCNNMetaArch constructor as input. See `object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py` for definitions of `FasterRCNNFeatureExtractor` and `FasterRCNNMetaArch`, respectively. A `FasterRCNNFeatureExtractor` must define a few functions:

- `preprocess`: Run any preprocessing of input values that is necessary prior to running the detector on an input image.
- `_extract_proposal_features`: Extract first stage Region Proposal Network (RPN) features.
- `_extract_box_classifier_features`: Extract second stage Box Classifier features.
- `restore_from_classification_checkpoint_fn`: Load a checkpoint into the Tensorflow graph.

See the `object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_resnet_v1_feature_extractor.py` definition as one example. Some remarks:

- We typically initialize the weights of this feature extractor using those from the [Slim Resnet-101 classification checkpoint](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models), and we know that images were preprocessed when training this checkpoint by subtracting a channel mean from each input image. Thus, we implement the preprocess function to replicate the same channel mean subtraction behavior.
- The “full” resnet classification network defined in slim is cut into two parts --- all but the last “resnet block” is put into the `_extract_proposal_features` function and the final block is separately defined in the `_extract_box_classifier_features` function. In general, some experimentation may be required to decide on an optimal layer at which to “cut” your feature extractor into these two pieces for Faster R-CNN.

For more information, please refer [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1af55e018eebce03fb61bba9959a04672536107d/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md) and this Github Repo for [Tensorflow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!